# SQL return 1 table data from another table column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hey guys quick question.
If i want to make a stored procedure to grab all information from 1 table from a different table column. 
More detail.....
table1 = users PK=accountid
table2 = Account PK = accountid 
The row i want to check is called role(int only contains 1 and 0).
so if role = 1  i want to check which accounts have role 1 and display all the users with that role number. if not 1 then 0 will display the other users??

Now i was thinking along the lines of

```
 USE [database]
 GO

 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Users_SelectAllByaccountRole]
 (
 @role int
 )
 AS

 BEGIN
 select * from Users 
 where (role = @role from Accounts) 
 && 
 (Users.accountid == account.accountid)

 END
```

But i do not know the syntax and i aint sure on my logic any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In T-SQL use AND OR operators. Do not use && ||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `Role` column is on the `Accounts` table, then it seems like a simple `INNER JOIN` will do...

```
SELECT u.*
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Accounts a on a.AccountID = u.AccountID
WHERE a.Role = @role
```

Comment: Thankyou very much works well and like a charm after doing this i found a mistake somewhere else but that is my C# side :(.

Comment: You're welcome :) thanks for the question. Also see [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) for more info on joins.